# Slide menu reomove when I clicking window

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code works true but. How do I remove her action when clicking window or document?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#icon").click(function(){
     if(! $("#icon").hasClass('active')){
    $("#icon").toggleClass('active');
     $("body").animate({ margin: "0 0 0 350px" }, 400 );
        $('body').css({
          'overflow': 'hidden',
          'height': '100%'
          });
     }else{
        $("#icon").removeClass('active');
         $("body").animate({ margin: "0 0 0 0" }, 400 );
         $('body').css({
          'overflow': 'auto',
          'height': 'auto'
          });       
     }


 });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `window, document` selectors and unbind `click` event using jquery method **[off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)** :

```
$(window ,document).click(function(){
    $("#icon").off('click');
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To remove action you can use two jquery functions to disable events. http://api.jquery.com/off/ and http://api.jquery.com/unbind/.

```
$(window,document).bind("click",function(){
   $("#icon").unbind("click");
   // or use
   $("#icon").off("click");
});
```